# Change specific elements of a list from string to integers in python

Tags: python, string, list

If I have a list such as

`c=['my', 'age', 'is', '5\n','The', 'temperature', 'today' 'is' ,'87\n']`

How do I specifically Convert the numbers of the the list into integers leaving the rest of the string as it is and get rid of the \n ?

expected output:

```
`c=['my', 'age', 'is', 5,'The', 'temperature', 'today' 'is' ,87]`
```

I tried using the 'map()' and 'isdigit()' function but it didnt work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the format of integers in your text, or there are just too many variations, then one approach is simply to try `int()` on everything and see what succeeds or fails:

```
original = ['my', 'age', 'is', '5\n', 'The', 'temperature', 'today', 'is', '87\n']
revised = []

for token in original:
    try:
        revised.append(int(token))
    except ValueError:
        revised.append(token)

print(revised)
```

Generally using `try` and `except` as part of your algorithm, not just your error handling, is a bad practice, since they aren't efficient.  However, in this case, it's too hard to predict all the possible inputs that `int()`, or `float()`, can successfully handle, so the `try` approach is reasonable.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your last comment, a common idiom in python is [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html?highlight=eafp) which as per the glossary is characterized by many `try`, `except` statements.

Comment: @AChampion I understand EAFP but it says, "assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions", in this case, nearly everything is an exception and we're catching valid keys!  I would agree it is Pythonish.

Comment: Understood (and agree), though I have found conditional types are another good candidate for EAFP.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that tries to convert to an `int` and if it fails return the original, e.g:

```
def conv(x):
    try:
        x = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return x

>>> c = ['my', 'age', 'is', '5\n','The', 'temperature', 'today' 'is' ,'87\n']
>>> list(map(conv, c))
['my', 'age', 'is', 5, 'The', 'temperature', 'todayis', 87]
>>> [conv(x) for x in c]
['my', 'age', 'is', 5, 'The', 'temperature', 'todayis', 87]
```

Note: 2 strings separated by whitespace are automatically concatenated by python, e.g. `'today' 'is'` is equivalent to `'todayis'`